# Entity Framework combining multiple queries into one

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, asp.net-web-api2

I have a query which it need to run 300+ loops every single call. It takes about 10 seconds to complete a call even on a new database. It's unacceptable for a WebAPI call.

```
var isAbnormal = false;
var list = new List<String>();

//Check date range, log them & return if there is any abnormal.
foreach (DateTime day in DateHelper.EachDay(startDate, endDate))
{
  var isActive = db.Operations.Any(x=>x.IsActive && x.Day == day);
  var object;
  var queryable = db.ObjectA.Where(x=>x.Day == day);

  if(isActive){
    queryable = db.ObjectA.First(x=>x.Day == day);

  LogUtil.Info($"{object.Name}");

  var isLogicACorrect = queryable.Any(x=>x.ObjectACount == 5);
  var isLogicBCorrect = queryable.Any(x=>x.ObjectBCount == 3);
  var isLogicCCorrect = queryable.Any(x=>x.ObjectCCount == 2);
  var isLogicDCorrect = queryable.Any(x=>x.ObjectDCount == 8);
  var isLogicECorrect = queryable.Any(x=>x.ObjectECount == 1);
  if(!isLogicACorrect){
    list.Add("Logic A is incorrect");
    isAbnormal = true;
    }

  //More logic codes & db calls here, which is just to select & validate.

}
return list;
```

How can I optimize the speed by combining all the queries into one? The loop content literally the same except the day.There are total 15 queries to be call on each loop, 4500 db queries in a complete loop.

Comment: Please post more code, do you have any logic to `continue;`? We need to see more to determine what can be changed

Comment: You should first fetch all the Active Operations for the given date range, and fetch all ObjectA for given date range. Once you have that list, you can query from the list instead of hitting the database everytime.

Comment: I've added more, but most of them are redundant, just to check if the database has the resources on the day itself.

Comment: I'm certain that the logic can be optimized considerably, but without looking at real code it's impossible to comment on precisely how best to do it. To optimize EF queries you need to consider the entities involved, their relationship, and all calculations/transformations you need to apply.

Comment: Stop writing code and thinking with code. What exactly are you trying to achieve? State it in plain English and then think about the solution to see if it makes sense. If it does, start writing code for your solution. Look at your code right now: what is `object`? You have not assigned anything to it and you are trying to `LogUtil.Info($"{object.Name}");`, why would that work? See the issue is with your solution. If you cannot explain your solution (algorithm) in plain English, don't try and code it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think in terms of sets and relational data and not procedurally.  It's not easy to determine exactly what you want from your code (which contradicts itself - `queryable` is set by a call to `db.ObjectA.Where(...)` which is an `IQueryable<ObjectA>` but then it is also set by a call to `db.ObjectA.First(...)`, which is an `ObjectA`; I'll assume you want the `IQueryable<ObjectA>` since later code references `queryable.Any(...)`) but here's my guess:

```
var days = DateHelper.EachDay( startDate, endDate );

var activeDaysIsLogicCorrectFlags = db.Operations
    // get days that are "active"
    .Where( op => op.IsActive && days.Contains( op.Day ) )
    // join with ObjectA's to filter for active ObjectA's
    // is there a nav property you could use instead?
    // use GroupJoin for use with `Any(...)` in results
    .GroupJoin( db.ObjectA, op => op.Day, oa => oa.Day, ( op, oaGroup ) => new
        {
            //Operation = op,
            // projecting Operation.Day since that's what your foreach loop is using
            Day = op.Day,
            IsLogicACorrect = oaGroup.Any( oa => oa.ObjectACount == 5 ),
            // if IsLogicBCorrect can be determined from the collection of ObjectA's:
            //IsLogicBCorrect = oaGroup.Any( oa => oa.ObjectBCount == 3 ),
        } );
```

The results are an `IQueryable` of an anonymous type that maps an "active" `Operation.Day` with your logic for `IsLogicACorrect`.  For your other `IsLogicXCorrect` flags, if they can all be determined using the `ObjecetA` group `aoGroup`, simply add them to the `GroupJoin` result selector (as shown in the commented-out property).  If those flags need their own groupings (e.g. need to use `ObjectB` group to determine `IsLogicBCorrect`, then add additional calls to `GroupJoin` as shown above but using their respective `DbSet` and properties.  For example, if you need to use `db.ObjectB` for `IsLogicBCorrect`:

```
var activeDaysIsLogicCorrectFlags =
    <existing logic from above>
    .GroupJoin( db.ObjectB, at => at.Day, ob => ob.Day, ( at, obGroup ) => new
        {
            // project all previous results
            at.Day,
            at.IsLogicACorrect,
            // new flag
            IsLogicBCorrecet = obGroup.Any( ob => ob.ObjectBCount == 3 ),
        } );
```